# marker in the osm Map with osmdroid

Tags: java, android, dictionary, marker, osmdroid

I am trying to display a marquer in OSM, but can't. I can display the OSM map and the location of my phone, but nothing else.

Here is my code:

```
public class Carte2Activity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    MapView mapView;
    MapController myMapController;
    MyLocationOverlay location = null;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener ll;

    ArrayList<OverlayItem> anotherOverlayItemArray;
    String[] sources;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        ll = new Myll();
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,0,ll);

        myMapController = mapView.getController();
        myMapController.setZoom(10);
        myMapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(48.785152*1E6), (int)(2.285156*1E6)));


        location = new MyLocationOverlay(getApplicationContext(), mapView);

       //ajouter la loc
        mapView.getOverlays().add(location);
        //afficher
        location.enableMyLocation();

    }      

    private class Myll implements LocationListener{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        run();
    }

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        location.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() { public void run() {
            mapView.getController().animateTo(location.getMyLocation());
            }}); 
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

androidManifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="comparateur.carte"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Carte2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I don't see how I can do that. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

Look at these lines of code:

```
        OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation);
        Drawable myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.person);
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);

        final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);

        currentLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, resourceProxy);
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.currentLocationOverlay);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am getting nullpointer exception at this line:currentLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
            new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                    return true;
                }
                public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                    return true;
                }
            }, resourceProxy);

Answer (score 2):

add markerThey all ate as did :)

working code:

```
public class mapcode extends Activity {
    globalvar appState;
    int stats=0;
    private MapView mapView;
    private IMapController mapController;
    private SimpleLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay;
    private ScaleBarOverlay mScaleBarOverlay;  
    ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem> currentLocationOverlay;
    DefaultResourceProxyImpl resourceProxy;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        appState = ((globalvar) getApplicationContext());





        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);  
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
      //  mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //кнопка ZOOM +-
        mapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        mapController = this.mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(2);

        this.mMyLocationOverlay = new SimpleLocationOverlay(this);                          
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(mMyLocationOverlay);

        this.mScaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(this);                          
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(mScaleBarOverlay);


        /////////////////
        resourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
        GeoPoint  currentLocation = new GeoPoint(55.860863,37.115046); 
        GeoPoint  currentLocation2 = new GeoPoint(55.8653,37.11556); 
        OverlayItem myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation);
        Drawable myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);

        final ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);



      myLocationOverlayItem = new OverlayItem("Here", "Current Position", currentLocation2);
     myCurrentLocationMarker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a);
        myLocationOverlayItem.setMarker(myCurrentLocationMarker);


        items.add(myLocationOverlayItem);



        currentLocationOverlay = new ItemizedIconOverlay<OverlayItem>(items,
                new ItemizedIconOverlay.OnItemGestureListener<OverlayItem>() {
                    public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    public boolean onItemLongPress(final int index, final OverlayItem item) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, resourceProxy);
        this.mapView.getOverlays().add(this.currentLocationOverlay);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void showOnMap(double lat , double lon){
    map = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    mapController = map.getController();
    myLocationoverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(map);
    myLocationoverlay.setEnabled(true);
    map.getOverlays().add(myLocationoverlay);
    GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
    mapController.animateTo(startPoint);
    mapController.setZoom(16.0);
    Marker startMarker = new Marker(map);
    startMarker.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.location));
    startMarker.setPosition(startPoint);
    map.getOverlays().add(startMarker);

}
```